# Having trouble with ethers.js queryfilter --> TypeError: contract.queryFilter is not a function

Tags: ethers.js, events

Trying to use queryFilter to find the value, sender and destination for a transaction event but im completely unable to, instead it is erroring out and telling me that queryFilter is not a function.

sneebler is a Contract object and sneeb is an event.

Does anyone know why this is happening, or how to properly use queryFilter?

[image]

Comment: You would need to share more code, instead of adding a screenshot just paste the code so its easier to follow, and make sure to include where sneebler is being declared and assigned

Comment: never mind, i had the wrong version of ethers, updating this fixed my problem